# People from a certain county have problems with registering in my Android app

Tags: android, http, countries

I have built a small game for Android, which have gotten a good amount of users.

The app will support both singleplayer (with highscore, stats) and multiplayer, so in order to do this I need users to register with a username and e-mail (show username in highscore, invite by mail / username).

When a user first downloads the app they will have to register to be able to play - this generally works fine, but not for all apparently. I have a database with users, scores etc. and a script which is called when the user registers, which checks if the username or mail is already taken.

The request to the server looks a bit like this:

```
try {
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
  String postURL = "http://somepostaddress.com/Script?... (params)";
  HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
  HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
  HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
  if (resEntity != null) {    
    //Read server response - if ok, save the username etc in shared prefs
    //If not ok, read the error message, and notify the user (email / username taken)
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Again - this works perfectly fine for almost every user... but apparently a lot of Dutch users get an error and can not register as everyone else. The error message they get, will be shown if an exception in the code occured or if the server response was not one of the responses the script can return.

The problem is ofc that I can not debug this or with the current version get more details about what and where something goes wrong. And I really do not understand why this only seems to happen to Dutch users - and not to all of them, but a lot indeed. Haven't had reports from users from other countries experiencing this.

Have done a regex to the username, so that only A-Z, a-z and 0-9 is allowed, so it should not be anything with special chars or anything.

Anyone ever experienced anything like this, and know what is going wrong or how this could be fixed - maybe the post should be done in another way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the domain on which your server is located for any potential blacklistings?  Do you have the ability to analyze based on IP address if the blocked users are sharing a particular service provider?

Comment: The server is a Microsoft Azure server, so I doubt that it would be blacklisted anywhere, but I guess it could be the case.
At the moment I don't really get any data that allows me to see if the people have the same provider, but I will try and add some more code to help me pinpoint the problem in the next release.